# How do I organize My Javascript Objects/modules?

Tags: javascript, api, object

So, I've been experimenting with modules in javascript and I've created several different js files with javascript objects that contain data that I am importing into my main files.

But, I'm wondering if this is the best way to store all this data should I automate something, or should I learn how to make an API to store all of this in?
what's the best way to store this information and import it.

Where is data like this usually stored by experienced developers?
Or is this already the best way to store all my data and I should just organize it all in seperate folders?

Here is an example of 1 of my files that I am using to store data and importing into my main js files.

`White_Keys.js`

```
/*  {White key Sounds} */
export const soundStores = {
    soundOne: document.getElementById('myAudio'),
    soundTwo: document.getElementById('myAudio2'),
    soundThree: document.getElementById('myAudio3')
};






/*  {White Key Grabbing} */

export const keyGrab = {
    key_F: document.getElementsByClassName('white b'),
    key_G: document.getElementsByClassName('white a'),
    key_A: document.getElementsByClassName('white g')
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my two cents:

There's no 'right way' or 'best way' for this, you can explore some small to medium size projects to checkout the folder structure, they are unlikely to be the exactly same but likely to have something in common.

For my company's project as example:
We mainly separate files based on file types and functions:

1. Page files goes one folder and maybe same category pages goes same sub folder
2. Store files of redux or mobx goes one folder
3. api requests goes another folder
4. css goes on folder and page css is created as file or fold depends on the complexity
5. Components goes one folder and sub folder if needed
6. Create correspond folder for other scripts or assets if any

I recon it's a common way to organize project files, gather similar files based on function or file extension, I also see other projects group all used files serves the same function together in one place, so if then want to move or copy this function to other project, just copy the directory.

So there are pros and cons of different approach, you can choose depends on your needs, and I assume you just a beginner, it'll come to you as your experience grows